Manhwa about a noble girl who was framed by another girl
The girl is then reincarnated and she then has to prove herself by showing some magic with water. She was executed in the public in her early life as she was not able to prove herself.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Is this I Am the Real One...?

A prophecy foretold that the Grand Duke would only have one water elementalist born from him. Though she lacks her father’s affection, Keira knows she’s destined for those powers. But after years of doing what was right and proper of a noble, she’s executed after the conniving Cosette appears, claiming to be the Grand Duke’s real daughter. But then—Keira wakes up with newfound purpose: make changes, allies, and even friends before it’s too late. Will it be enough before Cosette hatches her plot?

As noted in the summary above, a prophecy foretold that Grand Duke Ludwig Parvis would have only one water elementalist born from him, and his daughter, Keira, believed she was destined to receive those powers.
But then, when Keira was 18 years old, a girl named Cosette Weinberg appeared, claiming to be the Grand Duke's daughter by his first wife. And when Cosette manifested elemental powers two years later, Keira was accused of being a fraud and executed.




She then wakes up in the body of her younger self, two months before Cosette appeared, and resolves to make changes in her life.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.

ahh yess, this is it. Thankyou!
